# Find elements by xpath using regex

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to use selenium to find elements using Xpaths

Can I create a rule for all these Xpaths using the `contains()` method

My Xpaths list :

```
//*[@id="jsc_c_10"]/span
//*[@id="jsc_c_11"]/span
//*[@id="jsc_c_4n"]/span
//*[@id="jsc_c_2o"]/span
```

I tried the following code with no success:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'jsc_c_*+')]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct `regex` is not supported in `Selenium that usage xpath v1.0.`

You can use `find_elements` instead with contains as below.

```
list_of_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'jsc_c_')]/span")
```

and can `iterate` it like this :

```
for ele in list_of_elements:
    print(ele.text)
```

Note that ele is a web element, you can do stuff like `.text` or `.click()` etc.

or even first try to print the size like `print(len(list_of_elements))`

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'jsc_c_')]")
```

xpath doesn't support regex , you can use starts-with method instead

[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions) all functions can that are supported in xpath can be seen in this link